# jQuery How do I prevent the animation from resetting the scroll of the div?

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, reset

If I use the jQuery animation function to slide a #wrapper div (z-index:2) to the right and reveal a #menu div behind it (z-index:1), the #wrapper div reset's the scrolling the user has made on it.

[Here's the jsFiddle showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/pgXZG/). If you scroll on the #wrapper div (the one with the "Main #") and then you click on the "Open/Close Menu" link to activate the animation, the scrolling resets. I know this is caused by the `position:fixed`, but that is necessary so that when the menu is opened, the only div that scrolls is the #menu's div and not the #wrapper's div.

I've tried using `href="javascript:void(0)"` on the button that activates the animation and `return false;` on the click function. Nothing works.

How can I disable the #wrapper div from resetting the scroll?
or
How can I lock the #wrapper div scrolling once the #menu div is showing?

Comment: Remove the line $('#wrapper').css("position", "fixed"); and its working fine.

Comment: When the menu is showing, the scrolling on the #wrapper div needs to be disabled, so users can't scroll on it in any way (scroll bars, mouse wheel or finger swipes on touch displays). Is there any other way to lock the scrolling on the #wrapper div?

Answer (score 0):

Using `return false` in the .Click() callback function prevents the div from scrolling, but unfortunately it also forces both div's to have the same amount of scroll. The desired effect is for each div to have and maintain its own scroll amount consistently until the user reloads the page.

I worked around this issue by saving the amount of scroll on both divs and restoring them in the animation callback function. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGvjc/) showing my method.

Although this works seamlessly in desktop browsers, the "re-position and scroll" callback method depicted by

```
menu.css("position","fixed");
content.css("position","absolute").css("top","0");
window.scrollTo(0,contentScroll);
```

and

```
menu.css("top","0");
window.scrollTo(0,menuScroll);
```

are so slow in mobile browsers that you can see the div's re-position and scrolling which makes the animation look dreadful. This is a good method if you are designing for desktop or designing for mobile but value functionality over beauty. I didn't test it on tablets.